# Using linear gradient color stops for equal height columns rendering differently in chrome and safari despite both being controlled by -webkit?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, gradient

This has been driving me crazy - I have followed Chris Coyiers post about fluid width equal height columns. I chose to use the Doug Neiner Method which works great, the only problem is that when scaling down the faux columns are scaling down at different 'speeds' between safari and chrome. This means that safari keeps everything neat and inline and chrome seems to be off at all the important break points. I can't understand why this would be happening when they are both controlled by -webkit.

Basically this is my setup.

I have two 'rows' each one is an article that contains an image and then a div with a description underneath it. In safari when I scale the browser down to different breakpoints everything lines up. However in chrome a gap is created it's like the gradient background is scaling down faster than the images.

HTML

```
 <article class="rowContainer">
  <div class="rowOne">
     <section class="floatLeft textLightGreyArea">
       <img src="..." />
       <p>Description goes here</p>
     </section>

     <section class="floatLeft textDarkGreyArea">
       <p>Description goes here</p>
       <img src="..." />
     </section>
  </div>
 </article>


 <article class="rowContainer">
  <div class="rowTwo">
     <section class="floatLeft textLightGreyArea">
       <img src="..." />
       <p>Description goes here</p>
     </section>

     <section class="floatLeft textDarkGreyArea">
       <img src="..." />
       <p>Description goes here</p>
     </section>
  </div>
 </article>
```

CSS

```
     .rowContainer:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     content: "";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     font-size: 0;
     }

     .rowContainer {
     display: inline-block;
     }

    .rowOne {
       overflow: hidden;
       background: #c9c9c9;
       background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #c9c9c9),  
       color-stop(49.99%, #c9c9c9), color-stop(49.99%, #e0e0e0), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c9c9c9, #c9c9c9 49.99%, #e0e0e0 49.99%, 
       #e0e0e0 100%);
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #c9c9c9, #c9c9c9 49.99%, #e0e0e0 49.99%,    
       #e0e0e0 100%);
       }

       .rowTwo {
       overflow: hidden;
       background: #e0e0e0;
       background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #e0e0e0),   
       color-stop(49.99%, #e0e0e0), color-stop(49.99%, #c9c9c9), color-stop(100%, #c9c9c9));
       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e0e0e0, #e0e0e0 49.99%, #c9c9c9 49.99%,    
       #c9c9c9 100%);
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #e0e0e0, #e0e0e0 49.99%, #c9c9c9 49.99%, 
       #c9c9c9 100%);
       }

       .floatLeft {
       width: 49.99%;
       float: left;
       }
```

Comment: Not all WebKits are created equal.

Comment: Ok so is there a way around it - i was thinking maybe there might be a way for me to just target the gradient percentages just for chrome and use media queries to line it up at each breakpoint? It's causing a gap in chrome rather than scaling down inline so i need to find a way around it if possible.

Comment: See this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627292/webkit-linear-gradient-stops-render-incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer to this question while researching [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627292/)

It is due to a rounding error in blink's (google has branched webkit) rendering of gradients.

See [this pen](http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/fCsay) for a cool animated demonstration and links to bug (which are all in the other SO question too).